# Elasticsearch reindex JSON::ParserError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, elasticsearch

I was using `Elasticsearch` with Rails.

I type `User.reindex`, it works fine at beginning, but it threw this error in the halfway.

```
User Load (7.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` > 217316) ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1000
User Load (4.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` > 218316) ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1000
User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` > 219317) ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1000
JSON::ParserError: 795: unexpected token at ''
from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@rails320/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
```

I think there are some records of `user` are broken.

Can `elasticsearch` show the process of `reindex` step by step?

### Update

`localhost:9200` prints this

```
{
  "name" : "dMw7BW5",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_my_username",
  "cluster_uuid" : "cuQbjyM4S42sWpcHzDR9sQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.0.1",
    "build_hash" : "080bb47",
    "build_date" : "2016-11-11T22:08:49.812Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.2.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: what do you get after starting elastic search and hitting curl localhost:9200... ?

Comment: I've updated my question.